# IE + Watin unresponsive script message workaround?

Tags: internet-explorer, watin

I am using `WatiN` `2.0.20.0`  with `IE 8.0.7`. While using I am getting an error like

`"A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly. If it continues to run, your computer might become unresponsive.`"

When I searched for this, I found this as a solution

```
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175500
```

but in my machine I do not see a `Styles` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Styles`

How can i fix this issue pleases advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to create the registry key that doesn't yet exist.